# Request failed, Unexpected developer error, please try again later

Tags: android, google-pay

I have implemented Google Pay in android with Test parameters. In this, I used below parameters:

```
put("gateway", "example");
put("gatewayMerchantId", "exampleGatewayMerchantId");
```

And I received Google Pay Token successfully.

Now I am trying to implement this into my project where I use these parameters which is provided by my backend team.

```
put("gateway", "aci");
put("gatewayMerchantId", "some-merchant-entity-id");
```

but this is not working for me and this gives me the below error:
**Request failed, Unexpected developer error, please try again later**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWXUN.png)

I want someone who is already worked on this can help me out in this.

Comment: Hi @sanjay-sharma There is no `gateway` "aci". Most likely the correct value is "aciworldwide"? See also https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#tokenization

Comment: Did fixing the `gateway` value resolve the issue for you?